# Which of the following sets are equal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

```
A = {0, 1, 2}
B = {x ∈ R | -1 ≤ x < 3}
C = {x ∈ R | -1 < x < 3}
D = {x ∈ Z | -1 ≤ x < 3}
E = {x ∈ Z+ | -1 ≤ x < 3}
```

I said that A = B,C,D. Are there any others that are equal?

Comment: A is a set containing 3 integers. 
B is a set that contains at least 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, etc.
Do you see why these are NOT equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, you have $-1 \in B$ but $-1 \notin C$. For the subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, you have $-1 \in D$ but $-1 \notin A$, $E$ and $0 \in A$ but $0 \notin E$. Here are the sets written out more explicitly:

$$\begin{alignat*}{5}
& A && ~=~ \{0,1,2\} \\
& B && ~=~ \{x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 \leq x < 3\} && ~=~ [-1, 3) \\
& C && ~=~ \{x \in \mathbb{R} : -1 < x < 3 \} &&~=~ (-1, 3) \\
& D && ~=~ \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : -1 \leq x < 3\} &&~=~ \{-1,0,1,2\}\\
& E && ~=~ \{x \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : -1 \leq x < 3 \} && ~=~\{1,2\}
\end{alignat*}$$

Comment: user 1: I thought it would be helpful to write out the sets explicitly, since set-builder notation can be confusing to some people. Hopefully the poster will get the idea, and be able to complete the *rest* of his or her homework without asking the same question.

Comment: :) nice answer + nice comment :)

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

Two sets $U$ and $V$ are equal if and only if both:

- For every $x \in U$, that $x$ is also in $V$.
- For every $y \in V$, that $y$ is also in $U$.

Alternatively stated, if and only if both:

- $U \subseteq V$
- $V \subseteq U$